# How to upload a custom language data set to Azure Custom Speech Service?

Tags: dataset, customization, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

This service is currently in preview and appears to be out of sync with its documentation.

The documentation [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/Custom-Speech-Service/CustomSpeech-How-to-Topics/cognitive-services-custom-speech-create-language-model.md) shows a screenshot from a different console that looks nothing like the Azure portal pages for Custom Speech Service. The Azure SDKs that I checked don't seem to have any Custom Speech Service functionality at all.

So how can I upload a language data set to customize the vocabulary statistics?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is talking about this site: https://cris.ai/